# Angular 5 matDatepicker with matAutocomplete

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

Sorry they know if there is input in the input matDatepicker and matAutocomplete

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input [matDatepicker]="dp3" [matAutocomplete]="lote" matInput formControlName="Id_Lote" placeholder="Fecha vencimiento" class="form-control" id="Id_Lote" required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-autocomplete #lote="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayLote">
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredLotes | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.ExpirationDateProduct }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I get this error when I put the two together

```
DetailproductcreateComponent.html:59 ERROR Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
at eval (forms.js:2514)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at selectValueAccessor (forms.js:2503)
at new FormControlName (forms.js:7199)
at createClass (core.js:12449)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12284)
at createViewNodes (core.js:13742)
at callViewAction (core.js:14176)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: if there is a way to use the matAutocomplete and matDatepicker together

Comment: did you already find a solution?